# Closing a mobile navbar when you click a link within the navbar which loads a new page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have coded a mobile navbar which opens and closes when you click a burger. Within the navbar are 5 links. When clicking the links and loading a new html, the navbar remains open. I used javascript to code the opening and closing of the navbar - is there any way to add code which will solve my issue? Any help would be really appreciated.

CSS:
@media screen and (max-width: 750px){

```
.nav-area{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    right:0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 1000px;
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    text-align: right;
}

.nav-area li a{
    display: block; 

}

.nav-area.active{
    display: none;

}

.nav-area li a:hover ,
.nav-area li a.active
{
    background: none;
    color: #fff;
    transition: 0s;
}

.hamburger{
    display: flex;
}
```

}

HTML:

```
    <header class="header">
        <a href="#" class="hamburger">
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
            <span class="bar"></span>
        </a>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <ul class="nav-area"></ul>
        </nav>

        <script>
            const toggleButton=document.getElementsByClassName('hamburger')[0]
            const navBarLinks=document.getElementsByClassName('nav-area')[0]

            toggleButton.addEventListener('click',() => {
                navBarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
            })


        </script>

    </header>
```

Comment: So when you click one of the links, you want the navbar to close while the new page is loading? Or are you saying that when you go to the new page, the navbar is still open?

Comment: @SamSabin when i click one of the links in the navbar that loads a new page, im looking for the navbar to close rather than remain open.

Comment: Just during the time that the new page opens?

Comment: @SamSabin yes, so when a new page which is linked in the navbar opens, the navbar automatically closes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all links using `document.querySelectorAll` and bind `click` event on them so that on click, class `active` can be removed from `navBarLinks`

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('hamburger')[0]
const navBarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-area')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navBarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})

// GET ALL LINKS IN NAVBAR
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-area a')

links.forEach(l => {
  // BIND CLICK EVENT ON ALL LINKS
  l.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // ON CLICK, REMOVE active CLASS FROM navBarLinks
    navBarLinks.classList.remove('active')
  })
})
```

```css
.nav-area {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  right: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 1000px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-left: 30px;
  text-align: right;
}

.nav-area li a {
  display: block;
}

.nav-area {
  display: none;
}

.nav-area.active {
  display: block;
}

.nav-area li a:hover,
.nav-area li a.active {
  background: none;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0s;
}

.hamburger {
  display: flex;
}


}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <a href="#" class="hamburger">
    <span class="bar">|</span>
    <span class="bar">|</span>
    <span class="bar">|</span>
  </a>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="nav-area">
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>


</header>
```